# Regex for directory path format validation

Tags: c#, regex, validation, path

I'm trying to build a regex to validate directory path but I can't found a good way to do that.
Could someone help me?
examples :

```
/test/ -> could match
/test/toto/tata -> could match

\test\ -> could match
\test\toto\tata -> could match

//test/ -> could not match
\\test\ -> could not match
/test//toto -> could not match
/test\tata -> could not match
```

EDIT : i try this regex but it doesn't match all cases.

```
^(\/{0,1}(?!\/))[A-Za-z0-9\/\-_]+(\.([a-zA-Z]+))*$
```

Comment: This certainly would depend on the OS and file system used.

Comment: Just test for double slashes !(line.Contains("//") || line.contains("\\\\"))

Comment: @KlausGütter it's on Windows

Comment: @jdweng i want a regex to valide

Comment: Why do you need RGEX.  Regex should only be used when normal string methods cannot be used.  Regex is not very efficient.  A simply if statement will suffice : if(!(line.Contains("//") || line.contains("\\\\")) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to make sure there is at least one char in between the directory delimiters, the string can only start with a single directory delimiter and can optionally end with a directory delimiter.

As the `string.Concat(System.IO.Path.GetInvalidPathChars())` ([reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getinvalidpathchars?view=net-5.0)) returns `"\"<>|\0\u0001\u0002\u0003\u0004\u0005\u0006\a\b\t\n\v\f\r\u000e\u000f\u0010\u0011\u0012\u0013\u0014\u0015\u0016\u0017\u0018\u0019\u001a\u001b\u001c\u001d\u001e\u001f"`, you can actually put the `[^"<>|\u0000-\u001f]+` in the regex to match subfolder names and use

```cs
var pattern = @"^(?=([/\\]))(?:\1[^\\/""<>|\u0000-\u001f]+)+\1?$";
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%28%3F%3D%28%5B%2F%5C%5C%5D%29%29%28%3F%3A%5C1%5B%5E%5C%5C%2F%22%3C%3E%7C%5Cu0000-%5Cu001f%5D%2B%29%2B%5C1%3F%5Cr%3F%24&i=%2Ftest%2F%0D%0A%2Ftest%2Ftoto%2Ftata%0D%0A%5Ctest%5C%0D%0A%5Ctest%5Ctoto%5Ctata%0D%0A%0D%0Anot%20match%0D%0A%2F%2Ftest%2F%0D%0A%5C%5Ctest%5C%0D%0A%2Ftest%2F%2Ftoto%0D%0A%2Ftest%5Ctata&o=m).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=([/\\]))` - next char must be a `/` or `\` directory separator char (captured into `\1`)
- `(?:\1[^\\/""<>|\u0000-\u001f]+)+` - one or more repetitions of a directory separator char followed with one or more occurrences of valid path and directory separator chars, i.e. any chars other than `\`, `/`, `"`, `<`, `>`, `|` and the control ASCII chars
- `\1?` - an optional directory separator char captured into Group 1
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Thanks @Wiktor this is what i was looking for!